# Sending formatted dates to Database on PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a normal form with a single Date of Birth field (called DOB) which I send the data through the POST request as follows:

```
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$dob_db = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dob)));
```

I am stuck with a situation with multiple DOB fields on the same page which I have as below:

```
<input type="text" id="dob[]" class="datepicker" name="dob[]" placeholder="Day/Month/Year" value="" data-parsley-required="true"  data-parsley-required-message="Captain's Date of Birth is required." data-parsley-errors-container="#p1_dob-error" class="form-control">
```

I have other fields like name, etc which I collect the details and send to the database as below:

```
$name_array = $_POST['name'];
$mobile_array = $_POST['mobile'];
$email_array = $_POST['email'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]);
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($mobile_array[$i]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email_array[$i]);

mysql query here, etc, etc
}
```

I cant seem to get the DOB fields to work in the same way. Tried the same method also. Appreciate some help.

EDIT: I tried adding the DOB fields to this but it doesnt work. Everything else passes to the database fine but its only the DOB fields I am stuck with.

```
$name_array = $_POST['name']; 
$mobile_array = $_POST['mobile']; 
$email_array = $_POST['email']; 
$dob_array = $_POST['dob']; 
$dob_db_array = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dob_array))); 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) { 
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]); 
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($mobile_array[$i]); 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email_array[$i]); 
$dob_db = mysql_real_escape_string($dob_db_array[$i]); 

mysql query here, etc, etc
```

}

Comment: Your $_POST['dob'] needs to be looped, since you've defined it in the HTML that there are multiple $_POST['dob'] optional.

Comment: I tried this:

`$name_array = $_POST['name'];  
$mobile_array = $_POST['mobile'];  
$email_array = $_POST['email'];  
$dob_array = $_POST['dob'];  
$dob_db_array = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dob_array)));  
  
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {  
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]);  
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($mobile_array[$i]);  
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email_array[$i]);  
$dob_db = mysql_real_escape_string($dob_db_array[$i]);  
  
mysql query here, etc, etc  
}`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: When adding code for context please add it to your question with an edit. Anything longer than a very short snippet is almost completely unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @tadman I added the edit. Everything else passes to the database fine but its only the DOB fields I am stuck with.

Comment: I need to be using mysql only.

Comment: MySQL is the database. `mysqli` is your database driver for PHP. Your date fields *must* be [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, `YYYY-MM-DD`. There's many answers here on Stack Overflow covering that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tadman. Yes so I have another form with only one set of fields and that works fine with the DOB data being passed correctly. So I am assuming my format and everything is fine. My problem is with this specific instance where I am trying to pass the information from multiple input boxes with the "dob[]" name to the database after formatting. Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to assemble whatever you're receiving from the user into `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Unless you can clarify what you're receiving we can only guess as to how to do that.

Comment: So the data I collect in the input boxes for DOB are in the format: dd/mm/yyyy. The formatted data gets passed into the database fine in the other forms with single DOB input boxes. The ones with the array format I have tried here is where it fails. The database receives 0000-00-00 for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$fdob = str_replace('-', '/',  $dob);
$dob_db = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fdob));
```

Also is you mysql column set to `date` or user defined as `0000-00-00`?

I'm on mobile device so I can't post a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Klanto Aguntuk. I tried adding that, should that go inside the loop or outside? The formatting part? I am using arrays to get the information from the other input boxes but because of the formatting here I am not sure how to do this.

The column is set to date

Comment: Your should format it inside the loop. Otherwise you won't get the formatted date in every loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, eventually got it to work! Much appreciated!

Comment: Happy to hear that. :)